# How do we retrieve log file path in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am writing an API to fetch the log files from Google Cloud SQL. I need the log file name and path to fetch this information. I can see that the log file names are mysql.err, mysql-general.log and, mysql-slow.log from the log viewer interface.

Are those values fixed? Or Is it possible to change those values? If a user can change the log path, how do we retrieve the path from Google Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL instances run under “protected” VM instances that are internally managed. As you stated, you can view the logs via [stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#mysqllogs), but you can’t actually personalize paths or even access the actual log file. If for any reason you do need a log file, what you can do is create an [export](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) from stackdriver to Cloud Storage. From there you can simply use any Cloud Storage client library to fetch the files.

If you do need to have this flexibility, another option is to create a Compute Engine instance and run you own mysql from there having full access.